# If the file size is 0kb, it is not displayed on the gridview and the file is deleted

Tags: c#, image, gridview, uwp

I have a gridview that displays some files. I would like if the file size is 0 kb, then the file is not displayed and deleted, while other files are still displayed
Code:

```
StorageFolder cover = await komik.GetFolderAsync("cover");
foreach (StorageFile file in sortedfiles)
{
    bool bukuada = true;
    Buku buku = new Buku();
    buku.Judul = file.DisplayName.ToString();
    BasicProperties pro = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
    if (pro.Size != 0)
    {
        StorageFile thumbFile = file;
        try
        {
            thumbFile = await cover.GetFileAsync(file.DisplayName.ToString() + ".jpg");
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(await thumbFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
            buku.Cover = bi;

            datasource.Add(buku);
            loading.IsActive = false;
            this.itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

If I use the code above, then if there is a file whose size is 0 kb, then all files are not displayed. How do I get only 0 kb files that are not displayed and deleted, while others are still showing?

Comment: What is the problem you're having with your code at the moment? Don't you just need to add an `else` and then inside that delete the file?

Comment: The problem is if there are 1 or some files that are 0 kb, then all files can not be displayed. I want only 0 kb files that are not displayed and the file is deleted.

Comment: You should put `this.itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;` after the foreach loop.

Comment: Define `datasource` as *ObservableCollection*: `ObservableCollection<Buku> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Buku>();` and move the line `this.itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
` out of the  *foreach* loop (for example just before it). Then your *GridView* should get automatically updated, without the need of resetting the *ItemsSource*.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is setting the `ItemsSource` in the loop repeatedly, which is less efficient, but otherwise should not affect the result - even if there are some files of 0 size, they should be skipped and the "actual" files should cause the `datasource` to be updated.

My concern is regarding the following:

```
thumbFile = await cover.GetFileAsync(file.DisplayName.ToString() + ".jpg");
```

The `DisplayName` property has been known to sometimes return the file name **including**
 the extension. I would suggest rather using the following:

```
thumbFile = await cover.GetFileAsync( Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( file.Name ) + ".jpg" );
```

`Name` property returns the full name of the file, so if we apply `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`, the extension will definitely be removed, so the result will be what you want.

If that doesn't help, change the `catch` expression to `catch ( Exception ex )` and then put a breakpoint inside the `catch` block, because if the `datasource` variable is not filled out with data, there must be an exception happening beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

For you had set the `this.itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;` when the `pro.Size != 0`

Try to use this code.

```
StorageFolder cover = await komik.GetFolderAsync("cover");
List<StorageFile> deletedFileList = new List<StorageFile>();
foreach (StorageFile file in sortedfiles)
{
    bool bukuada = true;
    Buku buku = new Buku();
    buku.Judul = file.DisplayName.ToString();
    BasicProperties pro = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
    if (pro.Size != 0)
    {
        StorageFile thumbFile = file;
        try
        {
            thumbFile = await cover.GetFileAsync(file.DisplayName.ToString() + ".jpg");
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(await thumbFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
            buku.Cover = bi;

            datasource.Add(buku);
            loading.IsActive = false;           
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        deletedFileList.Add(file);
    }
}

// display the data source.
 this.itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;

 // delete the file
    foreach(var temp in deletedFileList)
    {
        try
        {
            await temp.DeleteAsync();
        }
        catch(IOException)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I get an error message: 'List<StorageFile>' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteAsync' and no extension method 'DeleteAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'List<StorageFile>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Rose https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.deleteasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_DeleteAsync

Comment: @Rose I fix it.